# How to resize Fancybox after submit?

Tags: ajax, fancybox

I have a page that opens using Fancybox. Within this page, I have a *Submit* button that causes my registration form to open. It opens fine, but the Fancybox is the same as the first page. How do I resize to fit my registration page?

Answer (score 0):

You could use this function:

```
$.fancybox.update();
```

Which auto-sizes fancyBox height to match height of content.

http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#examples